# TableLayoutPanel | adding new rows and controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am stuck in a dilemma here. I am trying to add new row to TableLayoutPanel in C# at the bottom and resize TLP everytime new row is added to, I have searched alot of places but I can not seem to find the right way to do that.

**PROBLEM**
When ever I add a row and add components to it, those components overlap the first row.

[image: OVERLAPPING]

**THIS IS HOW I AM ADDING NEW ROW**

```
private int AddTableRow()
{
    int index = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
    RowStyle style = new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 20F);
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(style);
    return index;
}
```

**THIS IS HOW I AM ADDING COMPONENTS**

```
private void AddControls
{
    int rowIndex = AddTableRow();  
    tableLayoutPanel1.Visible = false;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myComboBox1, 0, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myComboBox2, 1, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mytextBox1 , 2, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mytextBox2 , 3, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mytextBox3 , 4, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mytextBox4 , 5, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mytextBox5 , 6, rowIndex);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: The picture of your UI looks like you should be using DataGridView instead of TLP. I think TLP is meant to be set up design-time, not being a dynamic table with rows and columns coming and going.

Comment: I know that this CAN be done with TLP, but it doesn't mean that it would be wise to do so.

Comment: I have seen alot of tutorials they used to set it through TLP

Comment: By all means, I don't mind if you use TLP here. I would still use DataGridView.

Comment: so can you tell me why its not inserting in next row ?

Comment: No, can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Hmm..maybe you need to set up parent?

Comment: Did you somehow manage to fix this issue? I'm just facing the same problem...

Comment: @user1158652 , yes at every click on add button I increase the size of TLP as well. Rows are added at bottom but sizes remain constant so they overlap. I to this, TLP.height = TLP.height+24;

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember RowCount is not a reliable way to get the number of rows for whatever reason

Instead I would get the row to add to by dividing the total number of controls by the number of columns:

```
int rowNo = Controls.Count / numberOfColumns;
```

However unless you have a good reason for not using a DataGridView I would suggest you do. TableLayoutPanel is awkward to use dynamically

Comment: I think in the question it will be constant

Answer (score -1):

Just to be sure: in `AddControls()`, are you dynamically creating new comboboxes and textboxes for each row?I tried adding the same control instances over and over again and got the same behaviour that you are experiencing.